# JS How to validate a mobile phone number

Tags: javascript, numbers, include

I am new to coding an have been given this question;

Create a function that will receive the string of a mobile number. It should return true if the number is a valid UK number and false if not.

A valid mobile number may begin with '07' followed by 9 more digits.
  It may also begin with '+447' followed by 9 more digits.
  It may also begin with '00447' followed by 9 more digits.
  Anything else is invalid.

This is the code that I have created;

```
function validMobileNumber(num) {
    if (num.length != 9) 
    {
        return false
    }
    if (num.length = 9 && num.includes(07, 0) && num.includes(+447, 0) && num.includes(00447, 0)) {
        return true
    }
}
```

My code will be run against this;

```
describe("validMobileNumber", () => {
    it("returns false when passed a string of the wrong length", () => {
        expect(validMobileNumber("123")).to.equal(false);
        expect(validMobileNumber("0750617250638")).to.equal(false);
        expect(validMobileNumber("+447712368768724988")).to.equal(false);
    });
    it("returns true when passed a valid plain phone num string", () => {
        expect(validMobileNumber("07506172506")).to.equal(true);
    });
    it("returns true when passed a valid string with a + prefix", () => {
        expect(validMobileNumber("+447506172506")).to.equal(true);
    });
    it("returns true when passed a valid international phone num", () => {
        expect(validMobileNumber("00447506172506")).to.equal(true);
    });
    it("returns false when passed a string with invalid chars", () => {
        expect(validMobileNumber("07506189foo")).to.equal(false);
    });
    it("returns true when passed random other valid phone numbers", () => {
        expect(validMobileNumber("00447555123456")).to.equal(true);
        expect(validMobileNumber("+447676111222")).to.equal(true);
        expect(validMobileNumber("07898888643")).to.equal(true);
        expect(validMobileNumber("07766555432")).to.equal(true);
        expect(validMobileNumber("07989765490")).to.equal(true);
    });
    it("returns false when passed random other invalid phone numbers", () => {
        expect(validMobileNumber("004475551&&&23456")).to.equal(false);
        expect(validMobileNumber("-447676111222")).to.equal(false);
        expect(validMobileNumber("09898888643")).to.equal(false);
        expect(validMobileNumber("+449166555432")).to.equal(false);
        expect(validMobileNumber("00448989765493")).to.equal(false);
        expect(validMobileNumber("cats")).to.equal(false);
    });
});
```

Dose anyone have any suggestion to how ta make my code run properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Regular Expressions aka. regex. {[Regex Tutorial](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285)}

I was bored so I wrote it for you.

```js
validMobileNumber("123"); //.to.equal(false);
validMobileNumber("0750617250638"); //.to.equal(false);
validMobileNumber("+447712368768724988"); //.to.equal(false);

validMobileNumber("07506172506"); //.to.equal(true);

validMobileNumber("+447506172506"); //.to.equal(true);

validMobileNumber("00447506172506"); //.to.equal(true);

validMobileNumber("07506189foo"); //.to.equal(false);
validMobileNumber("00447555123456"); //.to.equal(true);
validMobileNumber("+447676111222"); //.to.equal(true);
validMobileNumber("07898888643"); //.to.equal(true);
validMobileNumber("07766555432"); //.to.equal(true);
validMobileNumber("07989765490"); //.to.equal(true);

validMobileNumber("004475551&&&23456"); //.to.equal(false);
validMobileNumber("-447676111222"); //.to.equal(false);
validMobileNumber("09898888643"); //.to.equal(false);
validMobileNumber("+449166555432"); //.to.equal(false);
validMobileNumber("cats"); //.to.equal(false);


function validMobileNumber(number) {
  let regex = /((07)|((\+|00)447)){1}[0-9]{9}\b/,
  result = regex.test(number);
  console.log(number, result);
  return result;
}
```